# Android GPS application not capturing location properly

Tags: android, gps, location

I am new to android and have just developed a GPS based application. It does the following -

1. Displays the path of the user using Overlays while the user is moving
2. Calcuates the total distance travelled & average speed

For obtaining the location of the user, if have registered the location updates using -

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);

Basically, I have tried getting the location every 10 seconds and then build the path accordingly

However, while testing this on my HTC Legend, I am facing few problems -

1. When I start recording the track, the GPS receiver icon starts animating on the top. At times, I don't receive any lcoation for as long as
   4-5 minutes
2. After I start receiving the updates, at times, the GPS receiver icon remains static, at that time location comes fine. But at times,
   it again starts blinking and I don't get any location after that, it remains blinking and I have to restart the app to make it working again

What am I doing wrong? Is the 10 seconds frequency too early? I can't use a Network provide since I have to build a accurate path, Network
providers don't give accurate path. How does the GPS receiver work? When does it blink? When does it stops?

Please help

Thanks !!

Comment: have you found a solution? btw which Android version does you HTC Legend has? I face a much graver problem oin my HTC Desire S (2.3.3). I am not able to get a GPS location fix. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you written "public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)" method in your locationListener class. It will give you updated location while moving.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. That is all done, that is why I am able to get location, but if you read my description carefully, I start getting problem after some time, and the gps receiver gets stuck in blinking mode

Answer (score 0):

The gps icon blinks when it can't establish communication with enough gsp satellites to find your location.